# Density Evolution of LDPC codes

Tags: error-correction, encoding

Can someone elaborate on the concept of density evolution?

So far, my understanding is that density evolution is essentially how many ones there should be in each row and how many in each column of the low-density parity check matrix.

However, how exactly is this determined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, I have discovered that there is no "formulaic" way of figuring out what the density evolution should be. However the rule of thumb is that *as the number of rows and columns increases, the number of 1s per each row and column should also increase.* A common number of ones used is about three 1s per row and column. Of course, one might need to add extra 1s in the rows to avoid even column counts.